# Finding records by matching set of IDs against a comma separated IDs in a field

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
Videos
ID(Int)  Industries(Varchar)
11       3,5,8
22       5
33       1,3
```

And this is the desired outcome:

```
Search In Industry Field        Found IDs
3                               11,33
1,8                             11,33
5                               11,22
1,5                             11,22,33
3,5,8                           11,22,33
1                               33
8                               11
```

What I am looking for is a way to come up a query that will do it. find_in_set() is a good function but will not work as it can only search for one id. And I can't change the table structure, as well. I can put each ID in find_in_set and make it a loop, but wondering if a better approach is possible!

Thanks,

Comment: This is what you get without proper normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you OR different FIND_IN_SETs together?

```
Search In Industry Field 3       
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(3,Industries) 

Search In Industry Field 1,8   
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1,Industries) 
OR FIND_IN_SET(8,Industries)
```

Comment: I have just done it this way though. Was looking to see if any other function (other than find_in_set) is available.

Comment: Nah, that's fine. If your table is heavily read and rarely written too, you could create an extra table with proper normalisation which uses indexes to speed up the readqueries - but the writequeries will have the additional cost of having to update the extra table and being slower. If there is enough more read then write, duplicating could outweigh the maintenance costs though.

Comment: Another IF: **if** your set of possible values is small enough, you can convert them to a bitmask, and just use logical operators which are blazingly fast. If your column type is not VARCHAR but SET, look at the `EXPORT_SET` function.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you maybe:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE industries LIKE '%andthenthevalue%'`

And then doing this for each value searched for by exploding the search input by a comma?

Comment: `1,8` won't find `11` then since `11` has `3,5,8`.

Comment: '3,5' will find '11,33'
'3,8' will find '11,33,11'
So it does work? Only problem is double entry's easy to solve :)